# TypeScript array type transform with keyof like method

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, keyof

I'm trying to achieve something like clone of one array type with specified value types as array with functions which return specified values.

Say we have array tuple like:

```
[string, number]
```

And what I want is to get generated type from it like:

```
[() => string, () => number]
```

What I've tried was to make type alias with `keyof` usage:

```
type tupleTransform<T extends Array<any>> = { [U in keyof T ]: (() => T[U]) };
```

And it almost worked except that it also checks for methods of `Array` so if I'll make:

```
const tupleTransformer: tupleTransform<[string, number]> = [() => 'a', () => 5]
```

It will fire me error that eg some method is not returning proper type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* you can do something like this:

```
type TupleTransform<T extends any[]> = { [K in keyof T]:
    K extends "length" ? T[K] :
    K extends keyof any[] ? Array<() => T[number]>[K] :
    () => T[K] 
}
```

It uses [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to distinguish between the array methods and the tuple numeric-string indices.

Let's make sure it works:

```
const tupleTransformer: TupleTransform<[string, number]> = [() => 'a', () => 5] //okay
const t0: () => string = tupleTransformer[0]
const t1: () => number = tupleTransformer[1]
const len: 2 = tupleTransformer.length;
const mapped: (string | number)[] = tupleTransformer.map(x => x());
```

Looks okay to me.  It might differ from a "real" tuple in some subtle way, so caveat emptor.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!